# Defining Maybe monad in Coq

Tags: monads, typeclass, functor, coq, theorem-proving

I want to define Maybe monad using type class in Coq.
`Monad` inherits `Functor`.

I want to prove `Some (f x') = fmap f (Some x')`, which is one of the monad laws.
I used `compute`, `reflexivity` and `destruct option_functor`, but I couldn't prove it.
I can't simplify `fmap` appropriately.

```
Class Functor (F: Type -> Type) := {
   fmap : forall {A B}, (A -> B) -> (F A -> F B)
 ; homo_id : forall {A} (x : F A), x = fmap (fun x' => x') x
 ; homo_comp : forall {A B C} (f : A -> B) (g : B -> C) (x : F A),
     fmap (fun x' => g (f x')) x = fmap g (fmap f x)
}.

Class Monad (M: Type -> Type) := {
   functor :> Functor M
 ; unit : forall {A}, A -> M A
 ; join : forall {A}, M (M A) -> M A
 ; unit_nat : forall {A B} (f : A -> B) (x : A), unit (f x) = fmap f (unit x)
 ; join_nat : forall {A B} (f : A -> B) (x : M (M A)), join (fmap (fmap f) x) = fmap f (join x)
 ; identity : forall {A} (x : M A), join (unit x) = x /\ x = join (fmap unit x)
 ; associativity : forall {A} (x : M (M (M A))), join (join x) = join (fmap join x)
}.

Instance option_functor : Functor option := {
   fmap A B f x :=
     match x with
     | None => None
     | Some x' => Some (f x')
     end
}.
Proof.
  intros. destruct x; reflexivity.
  intros. destruct x; reflexivity.
Qed.

Instance option_monad : Monad option := {
   unit A x := Some x
 ; join A x :=
     match x with
     | Some (Some x') => Some x'
     | _ => None
     end
}.
Proof.
  Admitted.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem arises from the fact that you ended the definition of the `option_function` with `Qed` instead of `Defined`.

Using `Qed`, you somehow 'hide' the internals of `fmap`. Then you can no longer unfold its definition (e.g. using the `unfold` and `simpl` tactics). Using `Defined` instead of `Qed` let you tell Coq that you intend to use the definition of `fmap` latter, so it should be unfoldable.